# Create MDAT from I-frame/P-frame fragments

Tags: h.264, mpeg-4

I am creating an MPEG-4 file from H.264 stream. H.264 stream comes in NAL format (EG: 0,0,0,1,67,...,0,0,1,68,...).
Each video frame is transmitted as multiple I-frame/P-frame fragments. For eg: Frame 1 contains approximately 80 I-frame fragments and Frame 2 contains around 10 P-frame fragments.

I understand that MDAT atom of the MPEG-4 file is supposed to contain H.264 streams in NAL format.

I would like to know how these fragments can be converted to a single I-frame before I can put it into MDAT atom of MPEG-4.

I do not want to use any libraries.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to convert H.264 Annex B NAL stream into MP4 file packets. In order to do that you need to:

- Split your original file into NAL units ( 00 00 00 01 yy xx xx ... );
- Locate frame boundaries: each H.264 frame typically contains a number of slices and optionally one of these: SPS, PPS, SEI. You'll need to parse the 'yy' octet above to determine what kind of NAL unit you are looking at. Now, in order to know the boundary of a frame you will need to parse the first part of each slice called 'SliceHeader' and compare 'frame_number' of consequitive slices.
- As soon as you know the frame boundaries you can form MP4 packets. Each packet will contain exactly one frame and and NAL units in this format:

  l1 l1 l1 l1 yy xx xx ...
  l2 l2 l2 l2 yy xx xx ...

so basically your replace each delimeter '00 00 00 01' with integer holding the length of this NAL unit.

- Then in order to obtain correct MP4 header you'll need to use MP4 muxer and populate correct 'AvcC' atom inside of a sample entry of your video track.

This is a rather tedious process but if you want to get into specifics you can study the source code of JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ): org.jcodec.samples.transcode.TranscodeMain , org.jcodec.containers.mp4.MP4Muxer